# How to auto run a script file when a file is saved?

Tags: linux

I am editing a project on linux server.I have to run a shell script every time I changed the source.
Is there a way that bind the save action to the script file.so I don't need to manually run the script when I change the source.

just like the git commit can hook a *.sh .
I want to use zend studio to edit the file on the server and when I save the file.it can trigger the  wanted script running.

Comment: What you really want is a [Reparse Point](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/109567/5560)

Comment: Using GruntJS, grunt-contrib-watch and [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) may also be of value to you.

Answer (score 11):

Use `inotify` in form of the `inotify-tools` and run a script on the server containing something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true 
do 
    inotifywait -e modify /path/to/watched_file.txt && /bin/bash /path/to/your-script.sh
done
```

This will execute the script whenever the file has been written to, but it might be that the `-e` list must be adapted for your case, see `man inotifywait`.

Alternative: Just *use* a git hook.

Answer (score 0):

I find [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) to be very handy for things like this. It works analogously to cron — you have user and system tables, and actions which trigger on events listed in those tables. That way, you don't have to have a purpose-built script always running for each watcher.

Note that, while the project is not defunct, it's not very active either, so don't expect too many new features. It's also not every widespread, so I wouldn't be surprised if it has a few security holes — I wouldn't make per-user incron tables available on a high-profile, critical multiuser server.